# 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with deleteCharactersInRange': Xcode 7.2 error creating archive to upload to appstore

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, app-store

In Xcode 7.2 when creating an archive to upload to App Store (using Windows > Organizer)

> I get the following error: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with
>   deleteCharactersInRange'

The following log is generated for the error:

> 2016-01-13 11:11:24 +0000  The store submission configuration response
>   failed with errors: (
>       "Error Domain=WorkerErrorDomain Code=-10001 \"Attempt to mutate immutable object with deleteCharactersInRange:\"
>   UserInfo={MZUnderlyingException=Attempt to mutate immutable object
>   with deleteCharactersInRange:, NSLocalizedDescription=Attempt to
>   mutate immutable object with deleteCharactersInRange:,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=Attempt to mutate immutable object with
>   deleteCharactersInRange:}" ), warnings: ( ), info messages: ( ).
>   2016-01-13 11:11:26 +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error
>   Domain=WorkerErrorDomain Code=-10001 "Attempt to mutate immutable
>   object with deleteCharactersInRange:"
>   UserInfo={MZUnderlyingException=Attempt to mutate immutable object
>   with deleteCharactersInRange:, NSLocalizedDescription=Attempt to
>   mutate immutable object with deleteCharactersInRange:,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=Attempt to mutate immutable object with
>   deleteCharactersInRange:}

I am using Swift 2 in my project and have integrated Objective-C based PayU payment Gateway library.

Is there someway I can track the source of the error, to resolve the issue.
I am able run the app successfully in the simulator and a real iPhone device.

Comment: let me know the code snippet of  usage of 'deleteCharactersInRange' in your code.

Comment: Avaan, I did a find in workspace for 'deleteCharactersInRange', but no search results returned. My query is that how do I track log back to the offending source code in my project.

Comment: Check in your code your are not assigning NSString to NSMutableString variables. PayU is using NSMutableString at in some of its methods.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem in Xcode 7.2
At the end, I used the Application Loader instead, and I succeed to upload the app.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Momachillies, the issue seems to be with xcode 7.2. Was able to upload using another macbook with xcode 7.0 using organizer.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am replying a ten months old post, but I still wish to post my answer in case somebody else ran into the same problem as me and desperately need an answer.

I have came across with the same error message too, and I found that I haven't add my app in iTunes connect.

In the end, I have my app added into iTunes connect and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try submitting from Xcode again if you get this error. The second try worked for me - was able to submit with no issues.

Comment: I get the same error when I try to use download dSYMs from teh organizer, it appears to be one of the many bugs of that release.

Answer (score 0):

**Try doing the next:**

1. Close xcode.
2. Try to clean derived data folder.
3. Open xcode then clean the project & archive using xcode.